# Exporting images from a SQL Server Table to a Folder using SSIS not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to export images from sql server 2012 to a directory using SSIS. I followed the steps as in https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2693/export-images-from-a-sql-server-table-to-a-folder-with-ssis/. There appears warning sign in OLE DB Source and when i run my ssis package, it shows one row affected.But when i search for directory it neither creates folder nor saves image.
My OlE DB Source :[image]

[image]

and my export column:
[image]

and the result:
[image]

Output is like this:
Warning: 0x80208386 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [18]: Rows sent to the error output(s) will be lost. Add new data flow transformations or destinations to receive error rows, or reconfigure the component to stop redirecting rows to the error output(s).
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80208386 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [18]: Rows sent to the error output(s) will be lost. Add new data flow transformations or destinations to receive error rows, or reconfigure the component to stop redirecting rows to the error output(s).
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
SSIS package "C:\Users\magnus_mani\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Integration Services Project3\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" finished: Success.
The program '[780] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: It could be an issue with your mapped drives.  If the account that is running the job is different from your account it may have D mapped to a different place.

Comment: what may be the solution then i changed the path for creating the directory and still not working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i created the folder name migImages in d drive and now the images are saved in that folder.I don't know why the folder was not created automatically..

Answer (score 0):

Can  you make a data conversion (dt_ntext) in between and try?